# unsigned right shift by negative number in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around negative unsigned bitwise operators.
For example, I have the code below. It prints out the value 7 and I don't understand why.

```
int num1 = -37, num2 = -3;    
System.out.println( num1 >>> num2);
// Essentially the same as System.out.println( -37 >>> -3); 
// I just wanted to emphasize that i am working with Integers
```

From my knowledge, the number -37 in binary format is as shown below.

11111111 11111111 11111111 11011010 = -37 (in decimal format)

If we are unsigned right shift of 3 ( -37 >>> 3, not -37 >>> -3), from my knowledge (please correct me if my theory is flawed or lacking key concepts), it shifts the bytes to the right by 3 and the 3 bits that fall out on the right most position appear on the left most position in a flipped down state (from zero to one), meaning that we get the following result.

00011111 11111111 11111111 11111011 = 536870907 (in decimal format).

However, if we apply an unsigned right shift of -3 ( -37 >>> -3), we get the result 7. I don't understand why it is returning 7. Could somebody please explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems counter-intuitive, but when shifting an `int`, only the last 5 bits of the shift amount are used, according to the [JLS, Section 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19).

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is `int`, then only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

This means that `-3` only has the last 5 bits used, or `29`.  Here's `-3` in bits to show what's going on:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101
```

The last 5 bits are `11101`, or `29` in decimal.

The right-shift distance is `29`, which means that the first 3 bits are kept and shifted all the way to the right.  Taking `-37`:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11011010
```

After the unsigned shift of 29 places, `7` is left:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000111
```

As you can see, a negative shift amount is confusing at best.  Try to avoid it and always attempt to use an actual number between 0 and 31 for the shift amount for shifting `int`s.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and also for the tips on when not to use them. I was just playing around with the bitwise operators and trying to grasp a greater understanding of how they work. 
I am guessing that negative unsigned right shift (that sounds weird) would simply make the code more difficult to understand, and it does make sense from your explanation.